# What is the meaning of 売るほうも売るほうなら、買うほうも買うほうだ。

Tags: grammar, translation, particle-を

I found this grammar structure

N1もN1なら、N2もN2だ

My book explanation says that it means both N1&N2 are terrible.

They provide this example of usage.

子どもが子どもなら、親も親だ。

Now, there is also this sentence, which I can't translate into English, please help.

> こんなつまらない商品を、売るほうも売るほうなら、買うほうも買うほうだ。

Also, why the を particle?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15930/5010

Comment: @naruto Oh thanks a lot Naruto sensei。 It makes sense now why they use を. So it means something like I don't like both the people who sell and buy this dull product. So なら here connects the AほうもAほうだ and BほうもBほうだ. Right?

Comment: @naruto by the way, you really can remember all the questions you answer even if it's from 4 years before. That's pretty impressive sensei.

Comment: この際、ついでに「どっちもどっち」という表現も一緒に覚えてしまうことをお勧めします。めっちゃ使い勝手が良いので。

Comment: I knew this was a recurring question, but I [often forget things](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15096/5010) :) I feel this なら can be interpreted as "If you can say X, you can say Y, too".

Comment: @l'électeur ありがとうございます